# drupal: commerce kickstart, change default/home page url

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

Hello:  I created a site for a client using **Drupal 7** and **commerce quickstart**.  Now that things are picking up, the client wants to make the estore a complete site; so I am adding the about, directions, join, etc. pages, but can't seem to figure something out.

Since the site was originally created with drupal 7 commerce quickstart, the default/home url takes the user to the store page showing all the items. So, for example, you type in ourStore.org and bam, you see the products in the store and can begin your shopping.  Well, I now want it so when users types in 'ourStore.org', the url points to the regular main/home page, and NOT the store page.

Then I need to create a link on the site to 'Our Store' for example, user clicks and goes to the store page that was originally the home page.

I must be tripping over something because I thought this would be a simple change.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: For those who run into this same issue, try creating a view of your store items then create a link to the view.  That seems to be working will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your home page can be set from `Configuration > Site Information` (under `System` section) which is at `admin/config/system/site-information` of your site.

Set the Default front page path to whatever node page you want to display.

Comment: Thanks NMC - the bigger issue that was muddying the waters for me was the eCommerce store itself.  I just created a view page and pointed a link to it after updating the home page url.

Answer (score 1):

You can your home page set from Site setting > Configuration > Site Information  which is at admin/config/system/site-information of your site.